# Infinite sums, comparison with other series over a subset of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have two convergent infinite sums. One over the primes and one over the natural numbers,

$$
S_P = \sum_{p} f(p),\ S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n),
$$
where $f$ is positive.

My question stems from the fact that the primes is a subset of the natural numbers. What I am wondering is if there are any conditions on $S_N, S_P$ that would allow us to deduce that $S_P \leq S_N$ since all terms in $S_P$ are present in $S_N$. Would absolute convergence be what I am looking for here?

Comment: How can $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ converge if $f$ is positive and increasing? For any convergent series, the terms must approach $0$.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Removing that part.

Comment: Well, if $f$ can be negative then of course we could have $S_P>S_N$. Why not?

Comment: Right, fixed the fix!

Comment: Ok, but if $f$ is positive then it is obvious that $S_P<S_N$.  Each partial sum for the prime sum is strictly less than the corresponding partial sum for the full sum.  Since the sum over the composite values is strictly $>0$ we must have a strict inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent then $\sum_p f(p)$ and  $\sum_c f(c)$ are also convergent, where $c$ runs over all composites. Since they are all positive terms, the series are absolutely convergent. Then use $\sum_p f(p)+ \sum_c f(c) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$.